# Angular 5 child routing

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have a problem regarding the routing in Angular 5. I would like to create a child route but when i type the url (for child route) the parent component gets loaded.
My routing:

```
path: 'user-admin/:id',
component: UserAdminComponent,
},
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserAdminComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: "final-exams",
    component: FinalExamsComponent,
  },
```

The two routes that belongs to the problem:

http://localhost:4200/user-admin/0

http://localhost:4200/user-admin/0/final-exams

Thank you for your help in advance! :)

Comment: This snippet looks strange. Should not the children be within the object above?

Comment: Do you have a `<router-outlet>` in your parent component ?

Answer (score 2):

> Have a look at the working solution

[Stack Blitz, Source Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-child-routing)

[user-admin/1](https://angular-5-child-routing.stackblitz.io/user-admin/1) // Hello will be printed

[user-admin/1/final-exams](https://angular-5-child-routing.stackblitz.io/user-admin/1/final-exams) // Hola will be the output

> Problem was:

You mentioned the same component in both Parent and Child Route & Children routes were not mentioned inside the parent route

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user-admin/:id',
    // component: HelloComponent, // No need to mention the same component, in parent
    children: [     // Children routes are inside the parent route
      {
        path: '',
        component: HelloComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: "final-exams",
        component: HolaComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the path before allowing the children to come into it:

```
{
  path: 'user-admin/:id',
  component: UserAdminComponent,
  children: [
    {path: '', component: UserAdminComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}, 
    {path: 'final-exams', component: FinalExamsComponent}, 
  ]
},
```

At the moment, you're putting a `}` before you start `children`.

Answer (score 0):

If the route `final-exams` and its content found in `FinalExamsComponent` need to be rendered alongside the content of `UserAdminComponent`,  you can use component less routes to achieve what you require. Like so

```
{
    path: 'user-admin/:id',
    component: UserAdminComponent,
    children: [
      { path: ''},
      { path: "final-exams", component: FinalExamsComponent },
    ]
}
```

This way, when you go to http://localhost:4200/user-admin/0 you will only render `UserAdminComponent` associated with `user-admin/:id` alone. Accessing http://localhost:4200/user-admin/0/final-exams would then render both the content of `UserAdminComponent` and of `FinalExamsComponent`

You can read about component less routes [here](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes#componentless-routes).

Answer (score 0):

Here in this case you dont need to add a child route to UserAdminComponent and open/close braces as follows.
Try this code.

```
    { path: user-admin/:id', component: UserAdminComponent,
            children: [
              { path: 'final-exams', component: FinalExamsComponent},
//add child routes here
            ]
    },
```